# Front audio is not working on 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 is installed on my computer. But front 5.1 mm audio is not working on 16.04. **Although it was working perfectly when I was on 14.04**.
When I format and reinstalled 16.04 problem was started...
Please help me anyone .[image]

Comment: Does the audio icon appear on service icons area (top-right side, with wi-fi, date/time, etc))? How: mute or sound icon? If you click on it, is the settings option visible and enabled?

Comment: Yes !!Back panel are working fine.

Comment: Ok, but does it has the front option? Is it disabled or doesn't appear?

Comment: see the picture for details

Comment: Ok. Are your system up to date? If yes, are your sound drive native or by the manufacturer? Go system configurations -  programs updates.

Comment: All are upto date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42268/discussion-between-gwarah-and-purnendu-nath).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: ALSAMIXER]

**ALSAMIXER** SOLVED MY ISSUE !! MY HEADPHONE SOUND LEVEL WAS AT 0. AND NOW MY FRONT SOUND PANEL WORKING PERFECTLY ALRIGHT !!

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same problem. Installed the GNOME ALSA mixer via Ubuntu Software, unmute the headphone, increased the volume and front panel is working.

[image here: GNOME ALSA mixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RPFp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with Kubuntu 20.4, but with a microphone. Tried unmuting it on alsamixer but tht didn't quite solve the problem.
As it turned out, Pulse Audio wasn't identifying the front panel because of the audio controller profile, so i googled a little bit and found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1289189/1150352) and was able to solve the problem. Here goes a TL;DR:

- First open up Pulse Audio Volume Control by typing in a terminal: `pavucontrol` (if you don't have it installed, just do a: `sudo apt install pavucontrol`)
- On the Configuration tab, change the audio controller device to `Analog Stereo Duplex`.
- Go to the desired input/output device tab, plug your device into the front panel and `identify wether your device is recognized or not`. If it isn't, then the next steps might not solve your problem.
- As changes made in Pulse Audio's GUI aren't permanent, we have to make them this way by editing a pulse audio config file.
- In a terminal, type `sudo vim ~/.config/pulse/default.pa`. If you are not familiar with `vi or vim`, replace it with a text editor you are familiar with.
- Append the following strings to the configuration file:

```
### Set Built-in Audio (HDA Intel) profile to Analog Stereo Duplex
set-card-profile 1 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

- Save the file, reboot and enjoy you system!